# AWS ELB logs missing requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elb

We are trying to match requests made to our backend instances with logs from our ELB.  Our application server logs clearly indicate that certain requests are coming in, but the matching requests are missing from the ELB logs.

The request is a POST request caused a couple of times per day by our mobile client in the wild.  We cannot reproduce the problem ourselves.

All requests to our app servers come through the same ELB.  What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After investigation by AWS support, they came back with information that some incomplete requests are not logged by the ELB:

> If the request is incomplete it will not be logged and if client leaves half way while doing the POST, ELB will gracefully close the connection with the backend, and it won't log the request.

These requests are sent to the backend instance however.  AWS support said they are looking into adding this information to the logs, but cannot provide an estimate when this would be implemented.